# Maven : Download and copy a single jar from maven to an external folder?

Tags: maven, jar, maven-plugin

I am trying to get one single jar required for a maven project inside an external folder(ojdbc jar).

I know use of `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` command.

It gives me the required jar files inside taget/dependeny folder. 
I am not sure if i have to put the dependancy inside plugin and then redirect it to some folder so that the jar gets available inside the folder while i do a build. This is my actual requirement. I need the jar to be downloaded while i do build.

Is there any way to download and copy the dependency in directory of my choice directly while i do build?

This is what i have been trying out. This copies all but i want a single dependancy to be downladed and pushed to a local folder.

```
<plugins>
...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

Comment: Doe you need this dependency during your build ? Means on the classpath of your project?

Comment: @khmarbaise i want this to be downloaded when i do a build and get stored in external folder

Comment: Why not put it into the build as well...without supplemental download ?